# How to customize mode-line-format?

Tags: mode-line, mode-line-format

I want to customize `mode-line-format` using `if` or `cond` etc., to let it show different text conditionally.

Here is a demo that I tried:

```el
(setq-default
 mode-line-format
 (quote
  (
   (:eval
    (cond
     (buffer-read-only
      (propertize " ⚑ "
                  'face (:foreground "red" :weight 'bold)
                  'help-echo "buffer is read-only!!!"))
     ;; (overwrite-mode
     ;;  (propertize "??"))
     (buffer-modified-p
      (propertize " ☡ "
                  'face (:foreground "orange")
                  'help-echo "buffer modified."))
     ))

   (:eval (if (or (eq (buffer-local-value 'major-mode (current-buffer)) 'ruby-mode)
                 (eq (buffer-local-value 'major-mode (current-buffer)) 'enh-ruby-mode))
              (:propertize "Ruby"
                           face (:foreground "green"))
            (:propertize "Not Ruby"
                         face (:foreground "orange"))))
   )))
```

But it does not show anything, I don't know where is wrong. Need help.

BTW:

I googled this, And got two good results:

- http://amitp.blogspot.com/2011/08/emacs-custom-mode-line.html
- http://emacs-fu.blogspot.com/2011/08/customizing-mode-line.html

And I saw two different code:

```el
(setq-default
 mode-line-format
 '(
   (:propertize var
                'face (:foreground "green"))
   ))

(setq-default
 mode-line-format
 (list
   '(:eval (if ...))
   ))
```

I don't know what's the difference.

---------------- UPDATE ---------------------

I found I can't put multiple `(propertize ...)` in one `(progn ...)`.
Is there any solution to solve this?

```el
(setq-default
 mode-line-format
'(
  (:eval
    (if (memq (buffer-local-value 'major-mode (current-buffer))
              '(ruby-mode enh-ruby-mode))
        (progn
          (propertize " ("
                      'face '(:foreground "#444444"))
          (propertize "Ruby: "
                      'face '(:family "Segoe Print"
                                      :height 80
                                      :foreground "red2"))
          (propertize (rbenv--active-ruby-version) ; `rbenv--modestring'
                      'face '(:foreground "cyan")
                      'help-echo '(concat "\nCurrent Ruby version: " (rbenv--active-ruby-version)
                                          "\nmouse-1: switch Ruby version menu")
                      ;; 'local-map
                      )
          (propertize ")"
                      'face '(:foreground "#444444"))
          )
      ;; (propertize "Not Ruby"
      ;;             'face '(:foreground "red2"))
      ))
))
```

This is solved, use `(list (propertize ...) (propertize ...)`.

Comment: I love the flag!

Answer (score 7, accepted):

If you want something that changes according to conditions then you pretty much need to use `:eval`, as in the second borrowed-code snippet.

There are several things wrong with your code.  `buffer-modified-p` is a function, not a variable; you forgot to quote some things; etc.  Try this, and then compare it carefully with your code:

```el
(setq-default mode-line-format
              '((:eval
                 (cond
                   (buffer-read-only
                    (propertize " ⚑ "
                                'face '(:foreground "red" :weight 'bold)
                                'help-echo "buffer is read-only!!!"))
                   ((buffer-modified-p)
                    (propertize " ☡ "
                                'face '(:foreground "orange")
                                'help-echo "buffer modified."))))
                (:eval (if (memq (buffer-local-value 'major-mode (current-buffer))
                                 '(ruby-mode enh-ruby-mode))
                           (propertize "Ruby" 'face '(:foreground "green"))
                         (propertize "Not Ruby" 'face '(:foreground "orange"))))))
```

Comment: Why need to quote those things, I'm confused. Can you tell me why? Or just give me some hints.

Comment: What if I want to display a symbol like `mode-line-process`, I use `(propertize 'mode-line-process 'face '(:foreground "orange"))` does not work. Why?

Comment: You need to quote things like the symbol `face` because `:eval` will try to evaluate them. You can try it yourself: Select the sexp in your code that is inside the `:eval`, and use `M-:` to evaluate it (after turning on `debug-on-error`. You will see the error raised. That is generally a good way to debug `mode-line-format` stuff.

Comment: You don't want to propertize the **symbol** `mode-line-process` (presumably). You want to propertize its **value**, which is a string (presumably). You need to spend some time with the Emacs doc (including the manual Intro to Emacs Lisp) and spend some time experimenting with evaluating simple sexps. `mode-line-format`, especially with the use of `:eval`, is probably not the best place to start.