# Fontify parts of the mode-line

Tags: mode-line, colors, vc-mode

How do I most conveniently fontify/colorize parts of my `mode-line`.

Specifically I want the vc branch named to have one color for master and another for other branches.

Comment: Do you have a minimal working example of how to display the vc master and/or another branch in the mode-line, such that it is just a matter of needing them colorized; or, do you need someone to figure out how to display the vc master and/or another vc branch as part of the question?

Comment: I guess this is one answer: https://emacs.stackexchange.com/questions/13652/how-to-customize-mode-line-format